# How can I pass in this data into a form submit call (similar to data parameter for an ajax post)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have the following code that submits data to an asp.net-mvc controller action via jquery ajax

```
   var queryString = "name=Joe&age=22&weight=200";
   $.ajax({
            url: '/MyController/Generate',
            type: 'post',
            data: queryString,
            dataType: 'json'
        });
```

this works fine and binds to the controller action parameter

```
public ActionResult Generate(MyParams p)
{
     Console.Write(p.name);
     Console.Write(p.age);
     Console.Write(p.weight);
}
```

The issue now is that I need to change this from ajax to being a regular form post (I need to use regular form post as I am now returning a file from the controller action).   I am trying to figure out how I can get that same querystring variable to get submitted as part of a regular form post (non ajax).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

try with html.beginform

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Generate", "MyController","name=Joe&age=22&weight=200", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmMyForm" }))
{
 // Your form elements
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want that data to be fixed you can make a form like this:

```
<form action="/MyController/Generate" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Joe" />
    <input type="hidden" name="age" value="22" />
    <input type="hidden" name="weight" value="200" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Otherwise, if you want the data to be editable, it goes like this:

```
<form action="/MyController/Generate" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="number" name="age" />
    <input type="number" name="weight" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: the issue is that i have a single string with all of the value in them up front so i wanted to avoid having to parse it into seperate fields to then put it back together again

Comment: You could bind the `onsubmit` event of the form and then make the ajax request as you were doing previously, remembering to return false in the called function to prevent the normal submit to complete. I don't know if this can fit your needs. Otherwise, if you need to use a classic form triggered by the classic submit button I don't know how you can do it without parsing the string.

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve my problem at all as i need a classic form submit